# Is there a name for this vintage 3-pin connector?

Tags: identification, connector

I am trying to find a suitable replacement for this connector for a photographic enlarger, and I need a name to search for. Is there a name for this particular pin layout or type of connector?

[image]

Comment: Is this a simple connector or an AC adapter/convertor going from one plug style to another, (or a F/M convertor?).  What is on the opposing side? Are there any other descriptive markings?

Comment: it plugs into a transformer which outputs 12v. The transformer has the corresponding socket as the output.

Comment: Bad news: the connector identification book thingie website doesn't know of any exterior power connector with 2× round, 1× blade http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NTK&n=exterior_power_conn&fl=000000000010320000000-36-|||

Comment: The overall shape is in the form of a standard IEC 320/60320 C14, though unshrouded, (at 12v that would be less important). The pins are likely purposely made non-standard so as to deter any connection to a standard AC house receptacle.

Comment: When and where was it made?  What manufacturer of enlarger is it?

Comment: @Marcus Müller Thank you for trying my utility, sorry that it wasn't helpful. If I find what this is, I will update the database.

Comment: @ron layters So, are you saying that it carries low voltage? Can you please post a picture of its female mate, on the transformer?

Comment: @DavideAndrea thank you for making this awesome tool! How would you like me to call it in the future? "connector identification book thingie website" certainly feels insufficiently nice.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You make a good point: "connector identification utility" is a mouthful. I need to come-up with a catchy name for it.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I can live with "Davide's connector identification utility" :)

Comment: I just came-up with "Identiconn". Do you like it?

Comment: here is a shot of the female socket on the transformer
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0htb.jpg

Comment: @DavideAndrea I like it!

Comment: # ron layters: Thank you. What I find interesting is that you can clearly see the marks in the tool that let the molding company insert any shape contact into any of 6 positions, and keys into any of 3 positions. That lets the molding company offer a variety of custom connector designs.